# "They get earlier every year!"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I've read the following dialog and have difficulty understanding the ending part.

A. Anyway, applications for a couple of interesting post-docs at Cambridge close early next month.

B:They get earlier every year!

What could the second sentence mean? They close earlier year by year?

I will be grateful for your support. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In view of the exclamation mark, I'm guessing that it's a reference to time seeming to pass more quickly as we get older. Regular annual events _seem_ to come round sooner than we expect.

Comment: ["I read" is better here than "have read"]. How is this an annual event?

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct is correct - speaker B is referring to the closure dates of the application becoming earlier, in somewhat of a lighthearted manner (they may not actually be aware of when deadlines were in previous years).

You will often hear this expression used with seasonal celebrations such as Christmas -

> A: "The supermarket has started selling turkeys in October!"
>
> B: "They get earlier every year!"

or events in nature:

> A: "I saw some daffodils flowering in February!"
>
> B: "They get earlier every year!"